# How to do sig test in SPSS?

Tags: spss

My client wanted me to run sig test for in SPSS (I knew that could be run using askia tool),I don't know how to do this sig test in SPSS, can anyone help me to run this?

Answer (score 1):

Sig. Test stands for **Significance Test**.. usually it is done to find out if there is a significant relationship/dependency between two variables (columns/fields)..in other words, to test whether one variable has an impact on another variable.

There are many different tests that can be used.. depending on what type of data you have..

for example, if you have **categorical data** (eg. 1 represents female, 2 represents female, etc.) you may use **Chi-Square** test.. which will find the **Goodness of Fit** test (GOF) and the **Pearson-Value** (p-value)..

If you have **continual values** you may use **correlation**..

In SPSS, you may explore all of those by going to: Analyze --> Descriptive Statistics --> Crosstabs

Hope this helps.